# How to add custom code to specific <li>s in wordpress while building navigation?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

the website in question is right [here](http://www.cars.evanparsons.net/) I'm trying to generate a CSS dropdown, however no such option is available in `wp_list_pages()`, I also won't be able to get the desired effect using WP Menus in the appearance menu (I used this method to generate my footer links)

This is ideal:

[image]

I know how to generate the menu, I just don't know how to get it under the "cars" menu without a hack javascript solution.

The ideal solution involves targeting the list item by the template name "Car Showcase" and allowing me to generate PHP/HTML (The code needed to make the dropdown) after it. Does this make sense to everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual way to create custom HTML for WordPress menu is to create a Walker

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class

Comment: I'm reading into this now, I will post back the code I used if it's what I need.

Comment: Yes, it works with wp_nav_menu of course and you can create a custom menu in the Administration Interface of WordPress. If not, the default is to return all pages in the menu.

Comment: I posted my answer to the problem I had, thanks for heading me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just create another menu and pull it from:

`wp_nav_menu( array( 'name' => 'menu-header'));`

Comment: This would generate the menu after I've already called wp_list_pages()

Comment: Perhaps but using a custom menu instead of some custom function & wp_list_pages() would be better, remember you can define custom URL's (these could be your post pages). Tart it up with CSS. Don't get me wrong I'm all for custom functions but Wordpress seems to cover what you're after and with a little bit of CSS magic - you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I extended the walker class in functions.php, it was way dirtier than it should be, and I'm still targeting the list item being generated by an ID, a solution which I am not fond of, but this is the cleanest solution I can come up with until I find a better one.

```
class Dropdowns extends Walker_page {   

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {

    if ($item -> ID == 55) { //checks if the page id is the list item I want to make my dropdown under
         $vehicles = query_posts('post_type=vehicles'); //my custom post that I want to dropdown

         if ($vehicles) { //check for no entries
            //code for drop downs go here
         }

    }     
}  
}
```